# Convert pdf prc format file to stp

Tags: pdf, 3d-model, u3d

I have a 3D model in PRC format extracted from a PDF file. I would like to convert this file into STL, STP, or another compatible format, allowing me to edit the 3D model using CAD software like SolidWorks. Is there any feasible method to accomplish this?

I tried CAD Exchanger,photoshop,Tetra4D Converter, all of these method failed